# Which beverages are least likely to give one a hangover? What induces hangover on a drink-to-drink basis?

Tags: hangover

Guinness, absinthe, and ouzo have never given me a hangover even after those rare nights of extreme consumption... Now, I do usually consume absinthe in the traditional way (with equal parts water) but, I've been truly amazed to wake up with no hangover after doing the, again extreme, things that I've done to my body with the stuff previously.  On the other hand, even when it's of excellent quality I experience hangover-like symptoms after drinking white and sparkling wines, and when I drink vodka.

Are some alcoholic beverages known to be least likely to cause hangovers?  If so, what characteristics of the drinks affect this?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I've put this on hold temporarily because it seems to be a discussion topic rather than an answerable question.  Please check out the links in the notice above and then [edit] the question, after which it will be reviewed for possible reopening.  Perhaps your question is about the drinks least likely to cause hangovers or the properties of drinks that do or don't cause hangovers?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I attempted to edit my question - I did not intend to receive opinion-based answers when compiling it. I'm unsure how an answer can be given from anything but personal experience here, to be honest...

Answer (score 3):

**Two things have to be considered**:

- The first, as Lying Dog said, is impurities. In fact, if they give taste, they also give you hangover
- The second, much more important is the fact that alcohol is diuretic. Once drunk, the alcohol is converted into several substances (in several steps) by your liver. The problem is once the last substances cannot be converted into anything useful, it will be ejected from your body. How ? By urinating. But urinating requires water. The problem is that if you do not drink water as much as needed, your body will take it from where it can, including from your brain. Now think about a sponge left without water inside and you'll have a good idea of what your brain looks like after a night, inducing hangover the next morning.

**To answer your question**, yes, Vodka is the most efficient alcohol to avoid hangover. But you can also avoid it by drink enough water while drinking alcohol (typically, if I'm at a party where I drink a lot of alcohol, I drink a pint of water after 2 or 3 beers)

Answer (score 2):

I used to work with a group of Russians. They introduced me to Wodka and told me that Wodka will never give you a hangover if you stick to Wodka only - and don't drink any other alcoholic beverages shortly before, in between or after. The reasoning was that hangovers feel like they do not so much because of the alcohol, but because of impurities. Good Wodka consists of extremely little impurities (a large part of it is just alcohol and water) and thus apparently is less likely to cause a hangover.

I found this to be true, provided the Wodka is of reasonable quality (Stolichnaya seemed to work well in this respect) and enough water is taken to avoid dehydration.

Answer (score 2):

I have voted to close, as this is entirely opinion based. The only hangover I have ever had was from my stag do - and it was caused by drinking everything all at once.

I can happily drink any spirits, beers, cocktails or wines with no ill effects the next day - but I have 2 friends who get bad hangovers from Vodka.

There is no single answer.

Comment: I'd say the question is experience-based more so, which keeps it on topic. Due to the nature of individual experience, I would agree that there could be no single answer, however...

Answer (score 0):

I can drink you a bottle of 80 degrees Stroh but have nothing from it the next day,because I follow 2 rules:

1. Drink a lot of water when drinking heavy(NOT Coca-Cola or other stuff,just WATER)

2. Never combine hard drinks like Vodka with Absinthe

Answer (score 0):

My own personal experience is that organic wine, red, white or sparkling is an alcoholic beverage which does not give you a headache. Seems that pesticides and additives in regular non-organic wine is the reason for headaches the next day.